# iterate array in pyspark /nested elements

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have input_data as

```
[[2022-04-06,test],[2022-04-05,test2]]
```

schema of the input_data is

```
 |-- source: array(nullable = true)                              
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull= true)
 |    |    |-- @date: string(nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- user: string (nullable = true)
```

I am looking **output** as

```
+-----------+--------+
| date      | user   |
+-----------|--------+
|2022-04-06 |test    |
|2022-04-05 |test2   |
+--------------------+
```

I have created a df from input_data  and applied explode on it further I am thinking to explode the result of it

```
df.select(explode(df.source))
```

is there any better way to achieve the **output** in spark sql or spark df

note I am getting @date and not date in input_data so applying spark sql is also some challenge

Comment: The explode function is sparksql... What output are you getting from the explode function that differs from what you want?

Comment: if I only explode source I am getting one column with two values first one is [2022-04-06,test] second one is  [2022-04-05,test2]
which is not my expected output

Comment: Have you tried to call the full structure of each column? Like: df.select(F.col('source.element.@date'), F.col('source.element.user')).show()

Answer (score 0):

Use select inline

```
df.selectExpr("inline(source)").show()
```

Comment: df.select(explode('source').alias("time_user_map")).\
select('time_user_map.user','time_user_map.@date').show()
I am able to solve it like this way as well , tried  the way which you gave .some how selectExpr is taking time.
is there any spark sql way for this  , explode work in sql bur the @ sign is giving issue